# Move items from Excel table to Calendar View

Tags: excel

I am trying to auto-populate an Excel calendar using an input table and am having difficulty with the formula to do so. I can get it to work off of the day but also need it to work off the month as well.

[image: input table]

[image: Calendar]

The formula that I tried is =FILTER(EVENTS[Leader],EVENTS[Day]=DAY(B3))

How do I get it to include the month column? In this instance, the goal is to only pull October dates to this calendar. As well as stack events that occur on the same day.

Comment: Try: `=FILTER(EVENTS[Leader],(DAY(B$3)=EVENTS[Day])*(MONTH($B$1&1)=EVENTS[Month]),"")` btw screenshot dont show the `Leader` Col.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya that did not work for some reason. My apologies, the Leader is the Events column A:A. I named that range "Leader".

Comment: When you say it didnt work what does it mean, does that meant it returns error or if you can clarify further

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya no error; however, if I state that Mike has an event on October 5, I have =FILTER(EVENTS[Leader],(DAY(F$3)=EVENTS[Day])*(MONTH($B$1&1)=EVENTS[Month]),"") in there and it returns nothing. Likewise, even using =FILTER(EVENTS[Leader],(DAY(B$3)=EVENTS[Day])*(MONTH($B$1&1)=EVENTS[Month]),"") for a October 1 event, I get zero return value. It remains blank....NEVERMIND, I got that part to work. NOW, if I have multiple leaders who have an event on the SAME DAY, how do I stack the results?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I answered my own question. I so appreciate your assistance! Thank you. This is resolved.

Comment: You should post your answer as answer and accept it.

Comment: Please make so that relevant information that you posted in comments are included in the body of the question.